# C++ 'php_sprintf' HOW to return this value?

Tags: php, c++, printf

```
void PrintMACaddress(unsigned char MACData[]){
    php_sprintf("MAC Address: %02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X\n", 
        MACData[0], MACData[1], MACData[2], MACData[3], MACData[4], MACData[5]);
}
```

Output code is:

```
return PrintMACaddress(MACData);
```

When i click 'build', it show this error:

error C2664: 'php_sprintf' : **cannot convert parameter 2 from 'unsigned char' to 'const char ***'

Please help, I'm newbie in c++ and I already search around many days for this error.

Comment: I don't know about PHP, but in C++ the first parameter to [sprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) should be a`char *` to write the output to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `php_sprintf` refers to the internal PHP function used when you write extensions for PHP. Then it has the same parameters as the `C` function `sprintf`.

Are you trying to print the MAC address to the standard output or to a string?

If you want to print to the standard output (and subsequently to a console), then use `php_printf`.
So you code can look like:

```
void PrintMACaddress(unsigned char MACData[]){
    php_printf("MAC Address: %02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X\n", 
        MACData[0], MACData[1], MACData[2], MACData[3], MACData[4], MACData[5]);
}
```

If you want to return the value instead of printing it to the output, the there are few points to note:

- When you work with strings in C++, you can represent it as either `char *` or `std::string`
- Using `std::string` is the C++ way to go.
- Using `char *` is more `C`-ish style. You have to manage the memory array by yourself (allocate on the stack or by using `new []` and `delete []`)

If I rewrite the method using `std::string`:

```
std::string PrintMACaddress(unsigned char MACData[]){
    char tmp_[32]; // The output string should be always 32 bytes long
    php_sprintf(tmp_,"MAC Address: %02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X\n", 
        MACData[0], MACData[1], MACData[2], MACData[3], MACData[4], MACData[5]);
    return std::string(tmp_);
}
```

If you want to (or have to) use `char *`:

```
char *PrintMACaddress(char *MACString, unsigned char MACData[]){
    php_sprintf(MACString,"MAC Address: %02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X\n", 
        MACData[0], MACData[1], MACData[2], MACData[3], MACData[4], MACData[5]);
    return MACString;
}
```

Here, the method gets one new parameter - pointer to allocated array of at least 32 bytes. It then returns the pointer to this array. You would use it like:

```
char macString[44];
PrintMACaddress(macString, MACData);
/* Use the string stored in macString */
```

or

```
char* macString = new char[44];
PrintMACaddress(macString, MACData);
/* Use the string stored in macString */   
delete [] macString;
```

**EDIT:** Updated second part of the answer with php_sprintf

Comment: Hmm.. void is not returing anything, so what i should write to let this function able to return this value? static or char?

Comment: Do you want to just print the value or return it from the function as a string? Version with `php_printf` just prints the value and doesn't return anything. The version with `php_sprintf` returns the value in `MACString` parameter.

Comment: Yes I would like to return the value but as you said justnow the function is declare using 'void' so it's not return anything right?

Comment: I updated the answer to deal with returning a string from the function.

Comment: Your code is very useful, you're a good programmer and tutor.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the second parameter can't be `unsigned char MACData[]`, which you set to; as the error mentioned. If it is necessary for it to be an `unsigned char`,  use `(const char *)` to convert it to an constant char.

```
void PrintMACaddress(unsigned char MACData[]){
    php_sprintf("MAC Address: %02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X\n", 
        (const char *)MACData[0], (const char *)MACData[1], (const char *)MACData[2], (const char *)MACData[3], (const char *)MACData[4], (const char *)MACData[5]);
}
```